# Android: Strategy to test In-App-Billing?

Tags: android, testing, google-checkout, in-app-billing

Can anyone tell me some best practices to test in app billing with real product using test account?
I have created a test gmail account and add it into my Developer Console. I actually can finish the in-app purchase. But i cancel the transactions in Google Checkout so that my credit card will not be charged. Now i want to test the purchase wit the same product again, than it doesn't work anymore because of the error "you already cancel order in app billing android". I search in Google and found out that i (the developer) can't change the pending status. So if i want to test the in-app-billing function again, i assume that i have to create a new productId.

Does anyone have better strategy to test the in-app-billing functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "fake" account to test the purchasing in the real product. Please see this link for everything you should need: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: While the link you provided is helpful, your description of it is not. A test account is not a fake account, and I don't know what you mean by "the real product." A synopsis of the methodology would be helpful.